# Why Haskell uses bottom instead of null in partial functions?

Tags: haskell, types

I'm reading about Haskell denotational semantics (http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Denotational_semantics) and I fail to see why, in a type, bottom "value" is placed at another level compared to "normal" values, eg why it can't be pattern matched.

I believe that pattern patching bottom would cause trouble as bottom denotes also non-terminating computations, but why should non-terminating computations and errors be treated the same? (I'm assuming calling a partial function with unsupported argument can be considered as an error).

What useful properties would be lost, if all Haskell types included a pattern-matchable Java-null-like value instead of bottom?

In other words: why wouldn't it be wise to make all Haskell functions total by lifting all types with null value?

(Do non-terminating computations need a special type at all?)

Comment: http://www.infoq.com/presentations/Null-References-The-Billion-Dollar-Mistake-Tony-Hoare

Comment: @Aivar The fact that recent OO languages like Kotlin and Ceylon start to differentiate between, for example String and String?, where the latter can be *null*, but not the former, should make you re-think your question. I bet, if Java et al were invented today, null would be banned, or restricted in a similar way as Haskell's *Maybe*.

Comment: @Ingo: Actually, I'm all for type system support in cases, where programmer should always check whether something is a "normal" value or "error value" -- I'm content with using Maybe/Either there. I was thinking more of really exceptional results, and possibility of pattern matching them. And now I see that I don't want just null, but a set of exception values. But after pondering this for some more, I must admit I'm not sure anymore, whether any of those really exeptional results are worth pattern matching at all (eg. OutOfMemory probably isn't).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can't get rid of non-termination without restricting the turing-completeness of your language, and by the halting problem, we can't generally detect non-termination and replace it by a value.

So *every* turing complete language has bottom.

The only difference between Haskell and Java is then that Java has bottom *and* null. Haskell doesn't have the latter, which is handy because then we don't have to check for nulls!

Put another way, since bottom is *inescapable* (in the turing complete world), then what's the point of *also* making everything nullable too, other than inviting bugs?

Also note that while some functions in the Prelude are partial for historic reasons, modern Haskell style leans towards writing total functions nearly everywhere and using an explicit `Maybe` return type in functions such as `head` that would otherwise be partial.

Comment: I don't think this is fair.  In strict languages non-termination is an effect, while in non strict languages it is a value.  You can't have a value of an "uninhabited" type in say ML, although you can have a function *`a -> Void*  because functions, not types, are lifted.

Comment: @PhilipJF: If you have a denotational approach, non-termination is always a value in your semantic domain. If you are like Bob Harper and don't believe in denotational semantics, you can claim non-termination is an effect and it doesn't exist in ML. I think Bob Harper knows a fair amount, but I also think Scott and Strachey knew better than him on this score.

Comment: @sclv, in a strict language, the semantic domain of values differs from the one of computations. Bottom exists in the latter (and no Bob Harper would deny that) but not the former. Types correspond to value domains, so are _not_ inhabited by bottom.

Comment: @AndreasRossberg: I think this holds for exceptions, but not bottom as such. In any case, such a distinction doesn't correspond to that which Philip JF made, nor, as far as I can tell, does it affect the answer to this question.

Comment: Do you have a source for that claim?  AFAIK You cant have a semantics for strict languages that does not make a distinction between values and something like expressions.  That is why every denotation for anything like ML I have ever seen has something like [a -> b] = [a] -> ([b] + 1)

Comment: @PhilipJF: I agree you need to distinguish between expressible and denotable semantics in many languages (and particularly those with effects). I just mean that bottom is denotable, even in a strict language!

Comment: I still don't think I understand what you are getting at.  I am not an expert in denotational semantics, but I thought the standard model of CBV languages uses pCpo and didn't give you bottoms.  So the denotation of `data Nat = Z | S Nat` would just be $\mathbb{Z}$ (the discrete CPO).  Perhaps I am missing something, but in ML you can't have a name that denotes divergence, although you can have divergent expressions.

Comment: I have to agree with @PhilipJF. Your claim that "Java has bottom" and the argument you base on it are misleading at best. The crucial point here still is that the types of a strict language are _not_ inhabited by bottom. Not acknowledging that fact _does_ render most of your answer unfounded, unfortunately.

Comment: @sclv: Thanks! I interpreted your answer as "bottom should be left for non-termination and Maybe should be used in representing partial functions", and this makes sense :)

Comment: Bottom in type theory is not the same as bottom in domain theory. If one looks at any basic work with semantic domains, such as Scott's "Semantic domains and denotational semantics" we find statements such as "every domain is assumed to have a least element." Strictness is treated in some detail there, and bottom is in fact essential to its treatment. You might way "b-but this is all about the value domain!" Well, recall that Scott gave denotational semantics to the untyped lambda calculus. So this should not bother us overmuch.

Comment: I should go back and read some of Scott's original work.  My understanding was that the use of pointed CPOs was a great move for understanding non strict language (which of course need a theory of strictness) but was suspect as a model for strict languages since you don't expect the denotation of a language without true products to be a CCC.  Instead, using the partial CPO category allows you to have semantic domains like the integers, while still being able to solve domain equations.

Answer (score 14):

My quibbling in the comments not withstanding, I think sclv answers the first part of your question, but as to

> What useful properties would be lost, if all Haskell types included a pattern-matchable Java-null-like value instead of bottom?
>
> In other words: why wouldn't it be wise to make all Haskell functions total by lifting all types with null value?

Here you appear to be drawing a distinction between non-termination and exception.  So, although it is impossible (because of the halting problem) to pattern match on non-termination, why not be able to pattern match on exception?

To which I reply with a question of my own: what about functions that never throw an exception?  Haskell has total functions after all.  I shouldn't have to pattern match to ensure that something is non-exceptional, if it is known to be non-exceptional.  Haskell, being a bondage and discipline language, would naturally want to communicate this difference in the types.  Perhaps by writing

```
Integer
```

for the type of Integers that are known to be not exceptional and

```
?Integer
```

for the type of Integers that might be an exception instead.  The answer is we do this already: Haskell has a type in the prelude

```
data Maybe a = Just a | Nothing
```

which can be read as "either an `a` or nothing at all."  We can pattern match on `Maybe` so this proposal doesn't give us anything.  (We also have types like `Either` for richer kinds of "computations that might go wrong" as well as fancy monad syntax/combinators to make these easy to work with).

So then, why have *exceptions* at all?  In Haskell we can't "catch" exceptions except in the IO monad.  If we can simulate exceptions perfectly with `Maybe` and `Either` why have exceptions in the language?

There are a couple of answers to this, but the core is that *Haskell exceptions are imprecise*.  An exception might arise because your program ran out of memory, or the thread you were executing got killed by another thread, or a whole host of other non-predictable reasons.  Further, generally with exceptions we care *which* exception we get out.  So what should the following expression result in?

```
(error "error 1") + (error "error 2") :: Integer
```

this expression should clearly result in an exception, but which exception?  `(+)` specialized to Integer is strict in both arguments, so that isn't going to help.  We could just decide that it was the first value, but then in general we would have

```
x + y =/= y + x
```

which would limit our options for equational reasoning.  Haskell provides a notion of exceptions with imprecise behavior, and this is important since the pure part of the language has perfectly precise behavior and that can be limiting.

Comment: Thanks! I agree with first part, that you should be able to distinguish statically between total and partial functions and Maybe/Either is a good way for that.

Comment: Now, the imprecise exceptions and trouble with catching -- wouldn't this thing be solved if Haskell used some proper values (eg. Exception String) instead of bottom here. Like bottom, these values would be in all types, and would propagate through computations, but they would be pattern matchable (ie. catchable). Normally one wouldn't write cases for them as they are really exceptional, but if one wishes to do so, it would be possible.

Comment: While I'm at it, there's a section in aforementioned wikipage (http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Denotational_semantics#Monotonicity) saying that pattern matching bottom would be bad because this would break monotonicity, and monotonicity is good, but I fail to see why is it good. (And if we place those exceptional values to the same level with proper values, we could even keep monotonicity). Should I write another question about this?

Comment: It would be nice if `error` were named something more clear like `impossible`.  It should never be used for code paths that can happen in correct code and is designed for when you want to crash the thread/program.  The only reason to catch it is to write to a log file in long-running servers.